# How to recover ZFS pool with errors that disappeared after reboot

Tags: 16.04, zfs

I had two ZFS pools set up `alphapool` mirroring `sda1` and `sdb1`, `betapool` just on `sdb2`. The OS resides on other partitions of `sda` so I can boot, see logs etc.

Yesterday `betapool` started getting errors. I don't know the root cause and to be honest I'm quite disappointed that ZFS did not prove to be plug and play for me. When I realized that something was going wrong, I did `sudo zpool status -x` and got two errors in `betapool`: one referred to a files in the pool, another to `<metadata>`. I tried to do some diagnostics, but most of my commands for that pool just hung with "D" (uninterruptible IO wait) in `ps aux`. `sudo reboot` hung as well, so I did a hard reset.

After the reboot one of the pools `alphapool` was mount fine, while the `betapool` is gone. Gone, but not quite...

```
$ sudo zpool import betapool
cannot import 'betapool': I/O error
    Destroy and re-create the pool from
    a backup source.
```

instead of

```
$ sudo zpool import smthelse
cannot import 'smthelse': no such pool available`
```

and

```
$ sudo zpool create betapool /dev/sdb2
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/sdb2 is part of potentially active pool 'betapool'
```

- Is there anything I could do to try to recover and import my `betapool`? (`-F` with `import` did not help)
- How can I figure out what was the root cause of ZFS failing as need to decide whether I should give it a second try or go with something more conservative though I really loved how easy and flexible it could be with ZFS.

P.S. `smartctl` on `/dev/sdb` shows no errors.

Updated with outputs for commands as requested in comments:

```
$ sudo zpool import
   pool: betapool
     id: 1517879328056702136
  state: FAULTED
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
    The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
    the '-f' flag.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
 config:
    betapool    FAULTED  corrupted data
      sdb2      FAULTED  corrupted data

$ sudo zpool status -v
  pool: alphapool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 6.15M in 2h36m with 0 errors on Sun May 14 03:00:39 2017
config:
    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    alphapool   ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sda1    ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb1    ONLINE       0     0     0
errors: No known data errors

$ sudo zpool online betapool /dev/sdb2
cannot open 'betapool': no such pool
```

Comment: `sudo zpool import` without a pool name should give you more information on the status/availability of additional pools. Please add the output of that command to your question.

Comment: `sudo zpool status -v` should give you verbose information. And as the pool has not been exported or destroyed, maybe `sudo zpool online betapool` would help or give more information about the error.

Comment: Thanks, ridgy. I've added the output that you've asked for.

Comment: As you wrote, `zpool import -f betapool` does not work either, so have your fingers crossed you have a good backup of your data ... As `betapool` is not redundant, it is not repairable. `corrupted data` may come from lots of reasons, maybe from your hard reset, from something directly writing to `sdb2`, flipped bits, ... Does not have to be hardware fault detectable by SMART. ZFS is not less reliable as other filesystems are, but works best with redundant disks. If you just have your `sdb2` left, you could use any other filesystem as well, I can't see lots of advantages with ZFS in that case.

Comment: See http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E/ as indicated in the error message.

Comment: As a last resort, if the data are very valuable and you have no backup, try to find someone familiar with zfs to follow some hints like https://serverfault.com/questions/297029/zfs-on-freebsd-recovery-from-data-corruption, http://mbruning.blogspot.de/2009/12/zfs-data-recovery.html and the [`zdb`manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/zdb.8.html)

Comment: Thanks, ridgy. ">> try to find someone familiar with zfs" that why I've posted the question here ;)

Comment: Ok, should have read: "someone  near to you" - it is very difficult to help with repairing filesystems when not sitting in front of the machine.